# Best practices to avoid naming clashes in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, naming-conventions

## Question

What is the best practice to avoid naming clashes in Coffeescript, especially given the context of nested scopes and Ajax callbacks?

## My Problem

I'm experiencing a name collision issue, where my naming convention dictates that the name for data in Ajax callbacks is the same as another object in my scope.

In the following code, I'm putting all my functions on the object `notifications`, but the data coming out of my Ajax GET requests is being named `notifications`.  The result is obviously causing errors:

```
# Handles initial get request.
notifications.init = ->
$.ajax 'notifications',
  type: 'GET'
  dataType: 'json'
  error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
    alert textStatus
  success: (notifications, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    if notifications?
      filteredNotifications = notifications.filteredNotifications notifications
      notifications.behavior notifications

# Triggers the notifications
notifications.behavior = (filteredNotifications) ->
  if filteredNotifications?
    $('#counter').html filteredNotifications.length
  if parseInt($('#counter').html()) > 0
    $('#counter').css
      'background': 'black'

# Removes notifications sent by the current user, copies for the other user,
# and notifications marked as observed.
notifications.filteredNotifications = (notifications) ->
  filteredNotifications = filteredNotifications.filter((notification) ->
    notification.recipients.username is $username() and
    notification.copy_for_user_id is $id() and
    notification.observed is false
  )
  return filteredNotifications
```

## Considerations

I've considered various abbreviations of `notifications` for the data object in the Ajax callbacks, but it decreases readability. Naming the parent object differently doesn't seem appropriate either.

Comment: It's not that opinion-based. The real question being asked here is "how can name clashes be avoided in programming, with an emphasis on nested Coffeescript scopes?". If you're going to close this, you should probably also delete most of the questions under the [naming-conventions tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions). Plenty of questions have been asked that are of far more dubious quality. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431658/naming-conventions-for-rails-migrations) definitely is and has a score of 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my pitch. As you've said, this subject is very subjective, but I've tried to keep this pretty standard.

Two major points:

- Abstracting logic away from namespaces is good practice, and results in less symbols to clash with. Coffeescript lets you instantiate anonymous classes, which helps a lot with this.
- I exclusively use the identifier `data` as the name of data objects in JSON callbacks. This reduces confusion for anyone reading a callback, and helps to eliminate clashes like the one you've encountered.

  ```
  notifications = new class
      init: -> $.ajax 'notifications',
          type: 'GET'
          dataType: 'json'
          error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
              alert textStatus
          success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) =>
              if data?
                  @behavior @filter data

      # Triggers the notifications
      behavior: (notifications) ->
          if notifications?
              $('#counter').html notifications.length
              if notifications.length?
                  $('#counter').css
                      'background': 'black'
              return

      # Removes notifications sent by the current user, copies for the other user,
      # and notifications marked as observed.
      filter: (notifications) ->
          return notifications.filter (notification) ->
              notification.recipients.username is $username() and
              notification.copy_for_user_id is $id() and
              notification.observed is false

  notifications.init()
  ```

I've made some other minor changes, and I took the liberty of making a logic change in `behavior`, which may not be perfect for your situation, but you should definitely revise the logic there anyway. It's unwise to use the DOM to store values you need in application logic.

Important to note is the use of the "fat arrow" (`=>`) in the `success` callback. It's required so you can bind the function to the correct context and have `@behavior` and `@filter` resolve correctly.

Comment: Could I get a reason for that downvote? And for the one on the question? As I see it, this question is good but opinion-based, and this answer is a satisfactory one given that context. Flagging the question seems perfectly reasonable, but downvoting it and my answer... doesn't. Obviously, I'm biased, but I don't think I'm *that* far off-base.